# Terrain and sculpting

Tags: texturing

I'm making a terrain by Blender Guru tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc

I wanna sculpt my terrain(not using displament map), but it distort textures in circle...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

I have the problem in shaders, used noise textures without connecting uv map:
[image]

Connecting like that:
[image]

Now its working perfectly!

Comment: Please use English on Stackexchange sites.